# Difficult SQL Statement (grouping and difference between two times)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I try to do a quite difficult sql select statement. Any hints are well appreciated :). Links etc. Here are my tables:

```
tbl_user
id     f_name       l_name    hourly_rate
1      Tom          Riddle    25
2      Frank        Smith     30
3      Lupin        Moon      35

tbl_entries
id     s_time   e_time   fk_user   fk_bank
1      08:00    10:00    1         1
2      11:05    11:50    1         2
3      12:00    18:00    2         1
4      13:00    15:00    2         1
5      10:00    12:00    3         2

tbl_bank
id     bank
1      a
2      b
```

I'd like to select and group them by tbl_bank. So my expected output should be:

```
id (tbl_user)     f_name     l_name       bank      total time (difference)   wage
1                 Tom        Riddle       a         02:00                     50
1                 Tom        Riddle       b         00:45                     18.75  
2                 Frank      Smith        a         08:00                     240
3                 Lupin      Moon         b         02:00                     70
```

I have something like this

```
SELECT
    id,
    f_name,
    l_name,
    hourly_rate
FROM
    tbl_user
    INNER JOIN tbl_entries ON tbl_user.id         = tbl_entries.fk_user
    INNER JOIN tbl_bank    ON tbl_entries.fk_bank = tbl_bank.id
```

which gives me all values but is obviously not grouped and without total time and .

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.f_name,
    u.l_name,
    u.hourly_rate,
    ( SUM( TIMEDIFF( e.e_time, e.s_time ) / 60*60 )                 ) AS "total time (hours)",
    ( SUM( TIMEDIFF( e.e_time, e.s_time ) / 60*60 ) * u.hourly_rate ) AS wage
FROM
    tbl_user AS u
    INNER JOIN tbl_entries AS e ON u.id      = e.fk_user
    INNER JOIN tbl_bank    AS b ON e.fk_bank = b.id
GROUP BY
    u.id,
    b.id
```

Comment: And `ORDER BY u.id, b.id;`. This is also assuming OP has the `s_time` and `e_time` columns as `TIME` type (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Total time shows something like 80500. How can I convert this to hh:mm:ss? If I don't use SUM it works absolutly fine.

Comment: @lupin without `SUM` it won’t perform an aggregate operation over the group and you’ll get meaningless rows (MySQL allows meaningless groups for some reason, other RDBMS will throw an error instead).

Comment: @Dai of course, but how can I solve it? So 80500 are 10:00:00 for example?

Comment: @Lupin I'd stick with returning an integer "seconds" value if your query results will be processed by another program because it's trivial for another program to convert seconds into whatever the program's language's timespan value type is. How are the query results being read? Will humans see the raw results directly?

Comment: @Lupin The reason I advise against formatting the SQL query results for readability by humans is because data formatting is a concern of the "view" (as in the human-user-facing layer of the software, nothing to do with SQL `VIEW` objects) not the query. Consider that not all cultures in the world use `:` as a time component separator, for example (this is also one of many reasons why we don't store dates as formatted text values inside databases).

Answer (score 0):

you could try using TIMESTAMPDIFF and go from there something like:

`SELECT tu.id, tu.f_name, tu.l_name, tb.bank
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,CONCAT(CAST(CURDATE() AS INT),REPLACE(CONCAT(te.e_time,":00"),":","")),CONCAT(CAST(CURDATE() AS INT),REPLACE(CONCAT(te.s_time,":00"),":",""))) * tu.hourly_rate wage from tbl_entries te
JOIN tbl_user tu ON (te.fk_users=tu.id)
JOIN tbl_bank tb on (te.fk_bank=tb.id);`

presume that your time is always current date (hence CURDATE() inside the query) and the SECONDS always start from 'hh:mm:00'

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a full datetime data type for the times for this for when the work shift passes midnight. But this should work.

SELECT tbl_user.id AS `id (tbl_user)`, f_name, l_name, bank, hourly_rate, TIMEDIFF(e_time, s_time) AS `total time (difference)`, (unix_timestamp(e_time) - unix_timestamp(s_time)) / 60 / 60 * hourly_rate AS `wages`
FROM tbl_user
INNER JOIN tbl_entries
ON tbl_user.id = tbl_entries.fk_user
INNER JOIN tbl_bank
ON tbl_entries.fk_bank = tbl_bank.id
GROUP BY tbl_user.id, bank;